# How can I make a ScrollViewer properly size dynamically with a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For reference, this is a **chat application**. This should give you some idea of a final goal.

Additionally, I am very new to WPF. This is one of my first applications and I am making this as a proof of concept. I've been using Windows Forms up until this point, so any comparison or reference to it would help me understand a bit better.

***So, the issue at hand:***

The chat box for my chat application is a `StackPanel` (should it be?) which is programmatically populated with `TextBlock` elements. **I need to find a way to scroll down this `StackPanel` once the available space runs out.** I also need it to automatically scroll to the bottom (like a chat would; you wouldn't be able to see the most recent message otherwise).

The question: ***How can I make a `ScrollViewer` properly size dynamically with a `StackPanel`?***

Additionally, I also need this `StackPanel` to size dynamically as the window is sized. This, in turn, would affect the scroll bar.

My current "solution" is to use a `ScrollViewer` with the `StackPanel` nested. However, the `ScrollViewer` and `StackPanel` do not size properly with a change in window size, as shown in screenshot #2. The XAML code and a screenshot of the designer is shown below.

```xml
<Window x:Name="Main" x:Class="dprCxUiDemoWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dprCxUiDemoWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="#FF171717">
        <TextBox x:Name="ChatBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="#FF4F4F4F" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.118,12.093" Margin="146,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="46" BorderBrush="#FFFF00F3" KeyDown="ChatBox_KeyDown"/>
        <Image x:Name="DprLogo" Source="/dprCxUiDemoWpf;component/Images/logo1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="123"/>
        <ScrollViewer  Background="Red" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="146,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="372">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ChatPanel" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="DimGray" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: A screenshot of my designer window.]

[image: A screenshot of the application running and failing.]
<sub>(source: [gcurtiss.dev](https://i.gcurtiss.dev/BCS6zTrP.png))</sub>

Please note the following regarding the first screenshot:
A. The black column (containing the logo) is simply the background color of the window; there is nothing there.
B. The gray portion is ChatBox (the `StackPanel`)
C. The pink highlighted box below is the text box where messages are entered.

I appreciate and accept any and all help!

Comment: "the ScrollViewer and StackPanel do not size properly with a change in window size" - they size 100% according to desired setting, namely `Height="372" `

Comment: @ASh Changing that property to Auto does not work correctly because the initial size will be incorrect. It'll scale to fit the initial height of the StackPanel, which looks like [this](https://i.gcurtiss.dev/8QzfSw35.png). Additionally, setting MinHeight causes the same behavior described.

Comment: some people who want adaptive/responsive wpf design, learn how to use Grid.RowDefintions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions. and generally learn about wpf layout system, especially coming from winforms

Comment: @ASh I'm sorry, I'm more of a hands-on learner and I figure out how things work over time. This is my way of learning WPF. I'm sure an answer will come along that will help me and also help to explain what I could be doing better as opposed to being condescending.

Comment: Start here: [Panels Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: You should edit your post and clarify your question. I suggest to read the documentation for [panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). WPF has different approaches than Forms that you should become familiar with.

Comment: @TinyTina I believe I have now edited my post to better reflect the actual question to answer.

Comment: A screenshot is nice. But it doesn't show how you have implemented your layout. Therefore we can't tell you what's wrong or how to improve it.

Comment: @BionicCode I understand. I can provide the full XAML as opposed to just the (what I think is) relevant XAML. This will help to give a better idea of the full layout. Edit: provided said information in question now

Comment: You should add two RowDefinitions to your Grid. Set the height of the bottom row to 'Auto' and add the TexBox and Image to it. Setting the top row's height to '*' will force the top row to occupy the remaining space. Then remove the height constraint from the ScrollViewer and all absolute positioning from the controls. Don't use Margin or RenderTransformOrigin to position elements inside a Grid. Use rows and columns instead. Margin is meant to fine tune the alignment. Using absolute positioning and dimensions prevents your UI from responding to size changes of their parent container properly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/grid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8. Just enter "wpf grid" into the search engine of your choice to find tons of tutorials that explain how to use the Grid properly.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find a way to scroll down this StackPanel once the available space runs out. I also need it to automatically scroll to the bottom (like a chat would; you wouldn't be able to see the most recent message otherwise)

You should read about data-binding and MVVM first. Usually you hold an ObservableCollection of items on your VM and bind them to eg a ListBox on your View.

Then you can scroll-down the ListBox, each time a new item got added to your collection:

```
private void ScrollRecordsListToBottom()
{
    if (RecordsList.Items.Count == 0)
        return;

    var lastItem = RecordsList.Items[RecordsList.Items.Count - 1];
    RecordsList.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
}
```